# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on Javascript import with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to import a jQuery library that I included in my code using the source `source: 'https://rails-assets.org'`. The problem is I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` because at the beggining of this package, it has the following line:

`import AnimationDisplay from './controls/animation-display';`

I don't know much about how this works, but I think this syntax is ES6 and that's why it is not being recognized.
How can I make Rails recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

You could change it into ES5 format.

```
const AnimationDisplay = require('./controls/animation-display');
```

Or look into using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 code down to ES5.